# WCF error handling service spammed with requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, silverlight, iis

We are running a Silverlight application running on IIS 7.5 using Forms authentication to sign in users. We have a RIA service which is protected using RequiresAuthentication, and an ErrorHandlingService and a LoggingService which is not.

Recently we seem to be spammed with requests to our ErrorHandlingService - in the order of 50 pr. second - producing the following output in the IIS log:

> 2013-10-01 11:19:12 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx POST
>   ...ErrorService.svc
>   - 80 - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+InfoPath.2;+MS-RTC+LM+8)
>   403 6 5 15

Now a little more detail on the setup:
The ErrorHandlingService has a single method accepting an Exception wrapper class, which will log the exception info into a table in the database, and the LoggingService accepts a LogMessage and same exception wrapper and logs the message to a file using NLog.
Whenever an exception occurs on the protected service, the silverlight client will first call the ErrorHandlingService to record the exception, and afterwards the LoggingService to log it to file.

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class ErrorHandlingService : IErrorHandlingService
{
    public string RecordError(ExceptionTransport error)
    {
        if (error == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var hex = HandMadeException.CreateFrom(error);

        var res = DiagnosticsHandler.DefaultInstance.HandleException(hex);

        var fb = res.GetFeedBack(DatabaseSink.FeedBackEntryId);
        var dbId = "";
        if (fb != null)
        {
            dbId = fb.ToString();
        }

        return dbId;
    }
}

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class LoggingService : ILoggingService
{
    private static NLog.Logger _logger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("Trace");

    public void LogError(LogMessage message, ExceptionTransport error)
    {
        string log = message.Message;
        if (error != null)
        {
            log = string.Format("{0}: {1}", log, error.ToString());
        }

        switch (message.Level)
        {
            case LogLevel.Trace:
                _logger.Trace(log);
                break;
            case LogLevel.Debug:
                _logger.Debug(log);
                break;
            case LogLevel.Info:
                _logger.Info(log);
                break;
            case LogLevel.Warning:
                _logger.Warn(log);
                break;
            case LogLevel.Error:
                _logger.Error(log);
                break;
            case LogLevel.Fatal:
                _logger.Fatal(log);
                break;
        }
    }
}   

public class ErrorHandlingService : ErrorService, IErrorHandler
{
    private LogHandlingService _loggingService = new LogHandlingService();

    public ErrorHandlingService()
        : base(WcfWebUtility.CreateFactory<IErrorHandlingService>("xxxxErrorHandlingService"))
    {
    }

    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        base.RecordError(error, OnErrorRecorded, false);
    }

    private void LogError(Exception error, string errorId, bool showUserMessage)
    {
        _loggingService.Log(string.Format("Error '{0}' occured on Ecofleet v. '{1}' for user '{2}'", errorId, ProductVersion.GetEcofleetVersion(), AutologUser.Current), Autolog.DiagnosticsService.Logging.LogLevel.Error, error);
    }

    private void OnErrorRecorded(ErrorResult result)
    {
        bool showUserMessage = false;
        if (result.UserState is bool)
        {
            showUserMessage = (bool)result.UserState;
        }

        LogError(result.ErrorRecorded, result.ErrorId, showUserMessage);
    }

    ... Shortened for brevity
}
```

So this is what's happening:

- In the IIS log output we see a ton of requests to the
  ErrorHandlingService, but none to the LoggingService.
- Nothing is entered into the database suggesting that the error parameter is
  null.
- The application works fine, and no users are complaining about
  errors. I would expect any user getting 55 errors pr. second to
  either  contact the support department, or at the very least log
  off...
- The client IP address seems to remain the same most of the
  time.

So is it possibly an (malicious) attack? Or could it be a client version discrepancy (if a new version is deployed and a client doesn't download it, would it be running an old client version against a new server?)? Or something else ... ?